# How do I write a swift function that will count the number of days without an entry?

Tags: swift, function, core-data

I am working on a project with NSManagedObjects where each object is a user entry that has a value and a date.  The app will be running a 7 day average and a 14 day average of the values the user enters.  I have already set it up to do the appropriate fetch requests, sum the values, and divide by 7 and 14, respectively. However, I am realizing that when the user first begins using the app these running average values will be very misleading, so I would like to set up a function that will evaluate the number of days out of the last 7 and 14 that do not have any entries so I can subtract that value from the denominator in these calculations.  I am a relative beginner and am having a hard time getting my head around how to write this function though, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Edit in response to Drekka:

The code I'm working from is below. I'm sorry for the broad question but I can't quite figure out where to start with structuring a looping function for what I'm trying to do and I haven't been able to come up with any examples or analogues in the searching I've done.  Basically I'm pulling all of the values entered in the last seven days but I'm trying to figure out a way to evaluate for days where no values were entered within the span of this fetch request.

```
func sevenDayFetch() {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Entry")

    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

    let sevenDaysAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
    let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: sevenDaysAgo!)
    let dateTo = Date()

    let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "entryDate > %@", dateFrom as NSDate)
    let toPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "entryDate <= %@", dateTo as NSDate)
    let sevenDayPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [fromPredicate, toPredicate])
    fetchRequest.predicate = sevenDayPredicate

    do {
        entryArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        var sevenDayArray: [Int] = []
        for i in entryArray as [NSManagedObject] {
            sevenDayArray.append(i.value(forKey: "Value") as! Int)
        }
        let sevenDaySum = sevenDayArray.reduce(0, +)
        let sevenDayAverage = sevenDaySum/7

        sevenDayAverageLabel.text = String(sevenDayAverage)
```

Comment: Please show some code and be be clear about what you are asking. Its best to show what you have tried to do to solve the problem and ask for help on where you are going wrong.

Comment: change `sevenDaySum/7` to `sevenDaySum/sevenDayArray.count`

Comment: I think the most correct solution is to not return anything until you have at least 7 (or 14) values to calculate an average on, `sevenDayAverageLabel.text = ""`

Comment: Kamran- thank you for the thought, but the user will be entering multiple values per day so I don't think that will work.

Comment: Joakim- I think you are right and I will likely change the label text to show 'running daily average' or something like that in cases where there are not 7/14 days of data yet. However, I am still very interested in understanding how to set up a function to count the number of days on which at least one value was entered.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to save the install date of the app in UserDefaults.

```
 func installDate() -> NSDate {
    var installDate: Date
    if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.dateInstalled) as? Date {
        installDate = date
    } else {
        installDate = Date()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(installDate, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.dateInstalled)
    }
    return installDate
}
```

Core data is not well suited for storing a single global value.  And you cannot infer the install date from core-data; not having a value for a date does not mean that the was not install then.

Once you know the install date you can adjust calculations and your UI, if it is less than 14 or 7 days.